# jQuery appended element click selecting parent too

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue using `.on()` to appended elements.

I'm trying to select and dynamically create divs that have the ability to be selected and have divs added to them. The problem I'm having is that when I select a dyanmic element that is inside an element that uses `.on()`it selects the parent too. I'm fairly new to jQuery so there may be a totally better solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
    var add_row_button = $('#add_row');        

    var row_count = 0;
    var selected_item = wrapper;

    add_row_button.click(function () {

        row_count++;

        var new_element = '<div id="' + row_count + '">' + row_count + '</div>';

        selected_item.append(new_element);

        $('#' + row_count).on("click", function () {
            console.log(selected_item);
            selected_item.removeClass("selected");
            selected_item = $(this);
            selected_item.addClass("selected");
            console.log(selected_item);
        });
    });        
});
```

```
<button id="add_row">Add row</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: can you post some HTML? and where does this `row_count` and `selected_item` come from? can you post their code too?

Comment: No problem. I just posted what I think you'll need.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ - stop Propagation. This stops the event from bubbling to the parent element up the DOM. _(edited for grammatical purposes)_

Comment: The point of `.on()` is so you can set delegated event handlers that will automatically apply to new elements that meet a specified selector criteria.  When done properly, you should NOT have to run any new code to hook up newly created elements.  If you show us a real sample of your HTML after a few rows have been added, we can advise what single line of .on() code would hook up the proper event handlers.  You're trying to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us your actual HTML, but here's an example that could work for you.

The idea of delegated event handling is that you attach an event handler to a parent object that is static (doesn't come and go).  Events on child objects then bubble up to the parent and the jQuery event handler on the parent checks the source of the event to see if it matches the desired selector.

So, if your container for these dynamically created events was `#container` and each dynamically create child had a class name of `dynChild`, you could hook up a click handler for all children matching that criteria with this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="dynChild"></div>
   <div class="dynChild"></div>
   <div class="dynChild"></div>
   <div class="dynChild"></div>
</div>

$('#container').on('click', '.dynChild', function() {
    // handle click on a child here
    // The this pointer will point to the element that was clicked on
});
```

You can then add/remove matching child objects without changing the event handling and their click events will automatically be handled by this delegated event handler on the parent object.  It's one of the more powerful capabilities for managing dynamically created/modified pages simply.

Answer (score 0):

[works!](http://jsfiddle.net/ccpM5/4/)

```
$(function() {

    //isolate code (optional)
    (function() {

        var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
        var addButton = $('#add_row');
        var row_count = 0;
        var selectedItem;

        //add a handler to the button
        addButton.on('click', function() {
            row_count++;
            var new_element = $('<div></div>').attr('id', row_count).text(row_count);
            wrapper.append(new_element);
        });

        //add the handler to the parent for the new items
        //so that we DON'T need to add a handler per new item basis
        wrapper.on('click','div', function() {
            if(typeof selectedItem !== 'undefined'){
                selectedItem.removeClass('selected');
            }
            selectedItem = $(this);
            selectedItem.addClass('selected');
        });
    }());
});​
```

Comment: updated the answer. i didn't notice the select logic the first time.